# eval() that contains "return" in the expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say the expression is:

```
var ex = "console.log(123); return false; console.log(456)"
```

Then I do this:

```
$('#id').change(function(){
    eval(ex)
})
```

When I run and change the value, I got error, **"Illegal return statement"**. The problem is **"return false"** where without it there's no problem.

Assuming I can't alter the expression (got from API), how to eval the expression while retain the break (return false) functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put it into a `new Function` instead:

```js
var ex = "console.log(123); return false; console.log(456)"

// $('#id').change(function(){
  const fn = new Function(ex);
  fn();
// })
```

Could also surround the string with `(() => {` and `})();`:

```js
var ex = "console.log(123); return false; console.log(456)"

// $('#id').change(function(){
  eval(`(() => {${ex}})();`);
// })
```

Comment: Wow that was fast! I've tested using ur second answer and its working. I have to wait another 8 minutes before can accept your answer (stackoverflow policy)